# SELECT query on hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm new to Hive and I would to select only column that terminated with 'id', for example, movieid, userid etc...

I've tried: `SELECT '*+(id)' FROM ratings WHERE movieid = 1;`    but it doesn't work.

How can I do a query like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you can use regex to match column names you are looking, below is answer,

```
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
select `.*id` from ratings WHERE movieid = 1;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives me a lot of values equal to .*id

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't worked for you, here I am able to match column names ended with id string. I have tested and worked for me. Could you post error message here.

Comment: I restarted docker and it magically works ... I have no idea why but that's okay

Comment: Great !! Happy coding.